# How to interpret histogram plot in tensorflow/tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, tensorboard

I compute `(n_samples,1)` rotation angles and pass them to histogram summary

```
angles_histogram = tf.summary.histogram("angles_histogram", angles)
```

and pass it to writer with the following command

```
angles_histogram_value = sess.run([self.angles_histogram])
rotations_writer.add_summary(angles_histogram_value, global_count - 1)
```

Angles are in radians and [in docs it is said](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram) that all values are used to build histogram. Unfortunately, I see nothing similar to what I would expect

[image]

How to interpet this plot?

Comment: What is the range of your sampled angles in radians? -2pi to 2pi? What is the expected 50 percentile? how about 10% and 90%?

Comment: These questions are ones for which hustograms are built. Histogram is above? What is a range? What is mean? What are percentiles? How to say this from histogram?